# C# internet explorer (internet options) in Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

- internet Options

  In C Sharp call InternetOptions function in Webbrowser Control

  OR

  Any DLL for InternetOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `WebBrowser`-control uses Internet Explorer, simply calling

```
Process.Start("InetCpl.Cpl");
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked !!

Comment: i use this code instead and it worked                                                            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("InetCpl.Cpl");